# Maven or Gradle build types/variants

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, gradle

The Android Gradle plugin adds support for build types and build variants, which let you select which version of your application you want to build at the build step (ex, debug or release).

This is a very useful feature for Gradle projects, as you can have 2 versions of your application that may behave differently in some situations, or have different configuration files or properties depending on the type of build.

Now, my question is: is there a similar feature/implementation for non-Android Java projects from Maven or Gradle? I am looking specifically for Java web apps, but I presume the question may have a larger target as well.

Comment: Maven has profiles. Gradle is programmatic so custom code choosing a configuration (or a plugin providing support).

Comment: As far as I can see, Maven profiles only allow for managing different configurations of the pom.xml file. The Android Gradle plugin not only provides you with a BuildConfig class which you can use wherever inside your code to check what build type is currently being run, it also provides the ability to specify a build type specific file for *any* file inside your project. Compared to this, maven's profiles look like a complete child's toy. Or am I missing something? Regarding Gradle, I haven't really understood what you mean.

Comment: Maven is very brittle if the build does not comply to its preconceived expectations. Profiles are a hack to coerce different flows. For Gradle, I meant that since you can write Groovy code it is easy to customize the build and task graph based upon flags. Plugins are is just that same Groovy code packaged for reuse. If an existing plugin for your case doesn't exist, its easy to write one by first flushing out code in the build files and then migrating to a custom plugin for others to enjoy.

Comment: I don't really believe that you understood what I meant by the BuildConfig and specific files for each build type, thus your answer being so vague. Long story short, none of these 2 build systems provide this functionality. Here's hoping for Gradle to implement the variants feature in the same manner Google did with their Android plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cutting it to the chase without vague answers, here is the official response from `Luke Daley (Gradleware Engineer)` on this matter:

> It is something we are actively working on. We are working to support
>   the notion of variants in a general way, so that there will be a
>   consistent approach across domains. It's a deep, deep, change though
>   so there is a lot involved.
>
> You can expect to see aspects of this rolling out in Gradle 2.5 and
>   on.

**Later Edit:** I've finally been able to get this working on a JavaEE webapp project by using SourceSets instead of Build Types & Variants. Considering that SourceSets have been around for a very very long time, apparently you could've done this ages ago... But not even gradle engineers were able to properly explain how to do so...

Anyhow, check out the `build.gradle` code below, where we use the same output directory for both SourceSets, then specify the location for the WAR plugin to build from:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceSets {
    main {
        output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources'
        output.classesDir   = 'build/classes'
    }
    debug {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
        output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources'
        output.classesDir   = 'build/classes'
    }
}

task assembleDebugWar(type: War) {
    from sourceSets.debug.output
    archiveName "ROOT.war"
}

task assembleReleaseWar(type: War) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    archiveName "ROOT.war"
}
```

Comment: Gradle v2.10 is currently out. Did this planned feature happen? If so, where can I find documentation on it?

Comment: Good question. I haven't searched for this every since. But here's what I could find for now https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#buildTypes

Comment: The top of that page lists several languages that this works for, but not Java (or any JVM language), which was what the OP was looking for. Also digging around a bit, it looks like that implementation of build variants has been around [since Gradle 1.9](https://docs.gradle.org/1.9/release-notes#build-multiple-variants-of-a-native-binary), and mostly unchanged since then.

Comment: Yes, I was initially looking for using gradle instead of maven for our Java web app, but like I initially said, this also applies for other languages as well. I've also found this right now, where it specifies Source Sets instead of build types/flavors: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html Are you going to be implementing this anytime soon? If not, I can try to get hold of a Gradle engineer again for a more complete answer.

Comment: I've managed to get it working with SourceSets after a lot of fiddling around. Check out the code above.

Comment: I do plan on implementing something fairly soon, but I'd also appreciate hearing a response from a Gradle engineer, no matter how long it might take. I'll study the code further when I get a chance.

Comment: I'm attempting to something similar, but haven't had much luck. I want to have a common (e.g. main), debug, and release. Debug and release both have a class that's named the same.  This works at the compileDebugJava/compileReleaseJava level, but the war task insists on using compileJava, which fails (interdependencies between debug/release class, and main code).